# Export xml data using BCP Command in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bcp

I am trying to export datable data in xml format but,Problem is like i can able to create xml file but data is not get writing in to the file following is my code I am trying.

```
DECLARE @cmd  VARCHAR(2000);

SET @cmd = 'bcp.exe "select * from emp FOR XML AUTO" queryout E:\rahul_1.xml -x -T';

EXEC xp_cmdshell  @cmd ;
```

And following is the output message I am getting after executing above code

```
NULL
Enter the file storage type of field XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B [ntext]:
```

can any body please suggest me on this

Comment: On a side note, [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms162802.aspx) explicitly says `The -x does not work when importing or exporting data.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dan you answer works, except one last thing.  BCP needs additional information about the source query.  Best idea to fully qualify the source of the data.

```
SET @cmd = 'bcp.exe "select * from [Database].[Schema].[Table] FOR XML AUTO" 
             queryout E:\rahul_1.xml -c -T';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the -x parameter (generate xml format file), specify -c (character file):

```
SET @cmd = 'bcp.exe "select * from emp FOR XML AUTO" queryout E:\rahul_1.xml -c -T';
```

Comment: Thanks for replay I tried this but it is also not working,following message i got after execution command
NULL
Starting copy...
NULL
0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1     
NULL

Comment: This command worked great for a very similar effort for exporting Extended Event outputs to an external file.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Try to use <kbd>-w</kbd> switch for exporting XML file in correct format

`DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(2000);`

`SET @cmd = 'bcp.exe "select * from [Database].[Schema].[Table] FOR XML AUTO" queryout E:\filename.xml -S MyServer\MyInstance -c -T -w';`

`EXEC xp_cmdshell  @cmd;`