# Writing JSON output in a file in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, json

I know that by using JSON Path and JSON Auto I can create an output in JSON in Microsof SQL. But what if I want to write this JSON output in a file? I have researched it on internet and haven't found any solution for this problem. Kindly help.

Comment: I wrote a Python script processing tool that will do this: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/execsql.  Your script needs to be run from the OS so this is not strictly "in" Microsoft SQL.

Comment: What about BCP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27153273/1662973